# Relation between speed and torque

Tags: three-phase, induction-motor

I am a bit confused of The relation betweeen the parameters mentioned above.

According to the below formula, speed is inversely proportional to Torque as:

T=HPx9549/Rpm

But i have been taught in my college that speed is directly proportional to torque because to rotate an object at high speed we need more torque(POWER).

Coperation is needed.

Comment: dc Motors are rating by kV/RPM no load and torque is proportional to current. Power = the product

Answer (score 2):

Speed is inversely proportional to torque IF YOU HOLD POWER FIXED. But that is usually not the way it works, that you hold power fixed.

Let me re-arrange that equation and break it down for you using standard units. When you are thinking of the mechanical power at the shaft of the motor, this is how it works:

P = torque * speed

Where P is power in Watts. Torque is in Newton-meters. Speed is shaft speed in radians per second.

So, if you speed up and keep the torque constant, that takes more power. If you increase the torque and hold the speed constant (like going up a hill in a car) that takes more power. That makes sense, right?

This is analogous to the physics of a mass moving against a force in a straight line.

P = force * speed

Where P is power in Watts, force is in Newton-meters, and speed is in meters per second.

Note: 1 revolution per second = 2 * pi radians per second.

Comment: I like to imagine that the unit of torque is Joule-per-radian. And that nicely cancels out right in your equation with speed in radians-per-second. In fact, keeping in mind Joules-per-radian as torque actually ***helps*** to remember that the speed used in the equation must be in radians-per-second.

Comment: Joule-per-radian. Haha! Nice. I will have to think about that, @jonk.